# My computer went to sleep whilst upgrading 16.04 to 18.04, now I can't log in

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, suspend, lock-screen

I was doing a distro upgrade via "sudo do-release-upgrade" but closed the lid to move the computer after some hours had passed. When I opened it again the lockscreen was there (though the installation command told me it would be disabled until restart) but it didn't let me log in. It said "unable to authenticate" without even giving me the option to put in my password.

I left it there in the hopes that it would finish installing anyway (it already said 18.04 in the bottom right by this point). Today I try to log in and it says something about clearing orphaned inodes and presents me with a lockscreen, but when I input my password, it goes black and shows me the clearing inodes screen again.

Is there a way to fix this without a clean reinstall?

Comment: If you can boot a live CD and mount the boot disk you can force a new password for you id: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-ubuntu-password-easily-from-the-live-cd/. But perhaps the problem is a bad filesystem and the Live CD will struggle to mount the disk....

Comment: The password doesn't seem to be the problem. If I introduce the wrong one it just does the normal thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having this same issue. I booted to recovery mode from grub, did a fsck check and a dpkg fix from the default menu. I rebooted and went into root, mounted the drive and ran "dpkg --configure -a".

Some daemons refused to run or install because of broken packages and whatnot (and I couldn't connect to wifi somehow), so after that, I booted into ubuntu and instead of logging in through the GUI, I went into the virtual terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F3 and logged in. Once I was in, I turned on my network card and connected, then I ran "sudo dpkg --configure -a", "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade". After a reboot, it worked perfectly.